# Age-based Conditional Statements in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, time, conditional-statements

--still learning rails here.. I want to write a conditional statement such as:

```
 if variable.created_at.method_for_checking_if_older_than(10 minutes)
     #code
 end
```

What statement or method can i use on a created_at value to fulfil the purpose of checking if it is older than a certain number of minutes/hours etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
if variable.created_at < 10.minutes.ago
    #code
end
```

Rails adds several such methods to the standard Ruby [Numeric](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Numeric.html) class, a full list is available from the Rails API documentation:

> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html